# Access protected field of inner class through inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

I am trying o access a protected field of Inner class through 
inheritance in another inner class. But i came across a problem:

```
  package a;

    class A{

        public class Inner{
           protected int i =5;
        }
    }

    package b;
    class B{

        public class BInner extends A.Inner{
         dsds
          void test(){
               System.out.println(i);  // that's works fine, i 
            }
        }

       void print(){
         System.out.println(new BInner().i)  // but why i cant access this field from here?  Compiler just says that there is protected access ... 
         }
    }
```

Is there is way how to access this field?

Comment: Your `BInner` class definitely doesn't _works fine_. Please post compilable code that represents your issue.

Answer (score -1):

The `protected` access modifier means that the field or method is available only to the class itself and its children. Since class `B` does not extend `B.BInner`, it cannot access `B.BInner.i`.

The most common way to work with access modifiers is to use **getter/setter pairs**, which you can declare in `A.Inner` (because that's where `i` is declared and `B.BInner` will inherit the methods):

```
class A{

    public class Inner{
       protected int i =5;

       public int getI() {
           return i;
       }

       public void setI(int i) {
           this.i = i;
       }
    }
}
```

Calling `getI()` on a `B.BInner` object will then return the value of `i`, and since it's `public`, it can be used anywhere.